# How to do SQL Server 2k8 with VS2010 CLR debugging

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008

Tearing my hair out in despair now after hours of fighting and googling. I'm trying to debug a simple CLR method. Setup: Visual Studio 2010, SQL Server 2008 R2 Express, Vista Business SP2. I'm a domain user but a local admin on the machine, and a sysadmin on the local instance of SQL Server. I created a new VS database project, pointed it to my db connection string (used this db before), then it asked me if I want to enable debuggig for the connection, to which I answered yes.

I verified that the project deploys fine (can see the assembly and its procedure appear in SQL Server Management Studio), and that I can call it just fine within SSMS. I then added the very same `EXEC` code to the `Test.sql` script in my db project, and marked it as the default debug script. I then set a breakpoint both in `Test.sql` and CLR code.

But when I hit F5 all I get is the following output:

```
Canceled by user.
Auto-attach to process '[2144] sqlservr.exe' on machine 'DAWID-PC' succeeded.
The thread 'dawid-pc\sqlexpress [54]' (0x13c4) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 'dawid-pc\sqlexpress [54]' (0x13c4) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 'dawid-pc\sqlexpress [56]' (0x109c) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 'dawid-pc\sqlexpress [56]' (0x109c) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The program '[2144] sqlservr.exe: dawid-pc\sqlexpress' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

And my debugging session ends right there.

I have `c:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\Remote Debugger\x86\msvsmon.exe` running; I can see a message saying `MyDomain\MyUsername connected.` appear every time I hit F5 in Visual Studio. I don't have a firewall running on my PC, and have no anti virus software installed.

Do you have any idea how to make it work? My real target was remote debugging but I thought I should try local first and iron out any setup quirks before venturing any further...

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem.  It appears to be an issue with your project being configured for .NET 3/3.5.  As soon as I changed my platform to .NET 2.0 I could hit my break points.  I can't wait until the have .NET 4 integration in SQL Server CLR types.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this error recently using VS2010 and SQL 2008 R2 (both installed locally). I switched off my firewall, etc. and still have no luck. Eventually I stumbled across what looked like a SQL Server memory issue. The SQL Log Files were showing a lot of AppDomain X unloaded messages. Anyway, the led me to here: http://www.johnsansom.com/sql-server-memory-configuration-determining-memtoleave-settings/#axzz1SZM5nqyF

and after changing my SQL Server -g startup option to -g384, hey presto the debugging worked !!

I'm not a SQL DBA so maybe someone can jump in and add to this if they have any knowledge of MemToLeave settings.

Ciaran

Answer (score 0):

1. in server explorer remove Allow SQL Server debugging, but set Application debugging
2. Start debugging and VS will request to set Allow SQL Server debugging.

Then it will work.

Abbas Shojaee

Answer (score 0):

Set your break-points in the source..,Build and deploy (Sql server projects will build and deploy when you run, but will not hit any break points you have set!.)
On the Server explorer make sure you have enabled Application Debugging and Allow SQL/CLR Debugging.

On the Server Explorer navigate to the clr stored procedure/function that you want to debug,
Right click and Step Into (Alt+F5) .. After 'Attach security warning' , you will see assemblies being loaded in the output window , followed by this, break point will be hit and you can continue usual debugging tasks.